# USB Input for 24 bit Recording, Is it possible?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, mixing, recording, audio-interfaces

I buy a Dynacord PowerMate 1000-3 Power Mixer devices, [Here](http://www.dynacord.com/en/products/7/5/73/251_pm1000-3.html). I think the output USB of this device send 24-bit audio for record. I need a device that get this USB output as input and record with 24-bit in very high quality.

> Is there any help or idea that introduce for me any interface or device for live recording that can use for getting output from Dynacord?

Answer (score 2):

Such a device is called a computer ;-)

Think of the mixer as an external sound card/adapter/interface itself - you plug in the USB cable into your computer and it will detect a new device. Install the driver and you now have a new sound device available. In e.g. Cubase you now see a new ASIO device.

Your new mixer/soundcard has the following specifications:

> Channels 4 In / 4 Out
>   AD/DA Conversion 24-bit
>   Sampling Rate 44.1 / 48 / 88.2 / 96 kHz
>   PC Interface USB2.0, Female Type B
>
> (source: [official specifications](http://www.dynacord.com/downloads/F01U131113_EDS_PM3.pdf))

With the mixer comes Cubase LE which you can use for recording. 
Like stated you can record up to four mono channels (or two stereo channels). For details take a look in the [manual](http://www.dynacord.com/downloads/Manual-PM3.pdf) around page 37-38.

Comment: Ok. I know it's called computer. but if we have one computer with on-board sound card or low quality sound card, this recording is not good. would you please describe an internal or external good sound card with SVM capability of Creative sound cards?, creative sound cards does not have a USB input for recording 24-bit. please describe me.

Comment: really my question is that which audio sound card or interface I can buy to record very high quality and get usb as an input from Dynacord?

Comment: The mixer itself is an external "sound card" and the specifications show that the quality is "okay" (24 bit / 96 kHz).. you don't need any on board stuff...